# Google Play - 32 bit and 64 bit confusion - App not updating

Tags: android, apk

I am not able to update my apk on play store after 32 and 64 bit issue. I am getting error like this. I tried everything. Split APK, Packages. But everytime I am getting following error. 
This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 174.

Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app.

[image: Error after upload package or APK]

here my gradle..

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.com"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 175
        versionName "4.9.6.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
//        ndk { abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86' }
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }




    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.thunder413:DateTimeUtils:1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha'
    //    compile 'com.github.xizzhu:simple-tool-tip:0.6.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    implementation 'ir.mtajik.android:advancedsmsmanager:1.0.6'
    //    implementation('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0'){
    //        exclude group: 'io.card'
    //    }
    implementation 'com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.1.2'
    implementation 'in.arjsna:passcodeview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.sunmi:DS_Lib:1.0.9'
    implementation 'com.github.curioustechizen.android-ago:library:1.4.0'

    implementation project(':localnet')
    implementation project(':near')
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.+'
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:android-device-names:1.1.9'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: As i see, you do not have static or shared c libraries. So most probably the problem is with any of the third party dependency.

Comment: I recommend you to check all the out dated third parties eihter they are containing c libs for 32 & 64 bit

Comment: check these two implementation project(':localnet')
    implementation project(':near')  projects if they have any only 32 bit libs

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57568509/apk-upload-error-in-playstore-64-bit-warning/57568667#57568667

Comment: @KingofMasses do i need to add  ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64' in project localnet and near gradle?

Comment: I don't think that is enough simply. Please check their latest updates whether they migrated to 32 bit and 64 bit support. Else contact them or write an issue for them in gitHub / any contactable medium

Comment: That won't solve your problem. Adding these abi filters looks for bit binaries

Comment: Finally I am able to solve the issue by following this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57660992/819135
Thanks @ManoharReddy